# Custom button in navigation bar - added and gets tapped but not visible

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

I try to add custom back button in navigation controller. I create button like this

```
    func setupBackButton() {
    let backButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonHandler(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    backButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    backButton.setTitle("<", for: .normal)
    backButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    let barBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = barBackButton
}
```

The problem is that button is being added (I can tap it and action on button is being executed) but i can't see button in controller - it is invisible.

Controller's color is blue.

Comment: Just assign the Frame to your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the frame of your button

```
backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
```

dont forget to add the action handler

```
func backButtonHandler(_ sender : UIButton)  {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
func setupBackButton(){
    let backBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action:#selector(backToPreviousVC))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn
    backBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
}

func backToPreviousVC() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

call setupBackButton() in viewDidLoad